Getting EADDRNOTAVAIL error when trying to deploy adonisjs v6 on render
I have an adonisjs API with MySQL and token guard configuration. I've been trying to deploy on render for the past day of two but I keep getting problems. I ran build on my local before pushing to GitHub then I set the root directory on render to "build". The build command is ``npm installand the start command isnpm run start`, which runs node bin/server.js. The logs show that build is successful , but it fails when it's about to start. The error says:

Error:
listen
EADDRNOTAVAIL:
address
not
available
216.24.57.252:10000

Here are my logs:
It looks like we don't have access to your repo, but we'll try to clone it anyway.
==> Cloning from https://github.com/Ikem-coded-it/hello-world
==> Checking out commit fc4fcaae4f72785e0aac10d6f744e9279748fc7c in branch main
==> Requesting node version 21
==> Using Node version 21.7.3 via environment variable NODE_VERSION
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running build command 'npm install'...
added 398 packages, and audited 399 packages in 13s
104 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
==> Uploading build...
==> Build uploaded in 9s
==> Build successful 
==> Deploying...
==> Requesting node version 21
==> Using Node version 21.7.3 via environment variable NODE_VERSION
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running 'npm run start'
> hello-world@0.0.0 start
> node bin/server.js
   Error:
listen
EADDRNOTAVAIL:
address
not
available
216.24.57.252:10000

and my deployment settings:


I'm not specifying a port in my env, render provides it's own port. Would appreciate if anyone that has experience with the same problem can point me in the right direction.
I have tried playing around with the deployment settings and env variables. I have tried running build during deployment the cd into build folder and npm run start but that didn't work, I was getting an trigger uncaught exception error.

The host 216.24.57.252 looks suspicious.
On Render, you should listen on 0.0.0.0: https://docs.render.com/web-services#port-binding

i was encountering the same problem. Check your environment variables and make sure everything's great there. You can also define the HOST to 0.0.0.0 manually into your environment variables.
